# why state updating itself? Without calling setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm beginner of React. Facing one problem don't know why.
Have one array of products into react state.

When user click on button(Through the sub component) I'm cloning current product array from state and then modifying it but state is updating without calling setState.
Help really appreciate. I want to know why the it's behaving like this.

Here is App component file:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            products: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    img: 'http://placehold.it/460x250/e67e22/ffffff&text=HTML5',
                    title: 'Laptop',
                    quantity: 1,
                    price: 250,
                },
            ],
            cart_products: [],
            total_price: 0,
            total_product: 0,
        };
    }

    addProductToCart = (id) => {
        let cartProducts = [];
        // Trying to clone first
        let productCopy = [...this.state.products];

        // Find specific product
        let newProduct = productCopy.find((item) => {
            return item.id === id;
        });

        // Now into new product I want to add some extra property
        newProduct['originalPrice'] = newProduct.price;

        // Here I want some other code.
        cartProducts.push(newProduct);

        this.setState({
            cart_products: cartProducts
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="container">
                    <h1 className="text-center">React.js Example </h1>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div className="col-sm-6">
                        <Cart products={this.state.cart_products} totalPrice={this.state.total_price} totalProduct={this.state.total_product} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-sm-6">
                        <Products products={this.state.products} onClicked={this.addProductToCart} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Problem is "products" array into state automatic updating. Here is the picture of React Chrome Extension

Before Method call
[image]

After method call:
[image]

Idea of application is just simple cart system. when user click on add product button I want to add specific product into cart. But I'm stuck how to fix this issue.

Comment: post the code of your render where you use the `onClick` event

Comment: I edited question added render method. Hope can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the spread object syntax to create new properties without mutating the original object in the state:

```
  addProductToCart = (id) => {
    const { products, cart_products } = this.state;

    // Find the relevant product
    let relevantProduct = products.find((item) => {
      return item.id === id;
    });

    // Now into new product I want to add some extra property
    const newProduct= {
      ...relevantProduct,
      originalPrice: relevantProduct.price
    };

    this.setState({
      cart_products: [...cart_products, newProduct]
    });
  }
```

Running example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: [
        {
          id: 1,
          img: 'http://placehold.it/460x250/e67e22/ffffff&text=HTML5',
          title: 'Laptop',
          quantity: 1,
          price: 250,
        },
      ],
      cart_products: [],
      total_price: 0,
      total_product: 0,
    };
  }

  addProductToCart = (id) => {
    const { products, cart_products } = this.state;

    // Find the relevant product
    let relevantProduct = products.find((item) => {
      return item.id === id;
    });

    // Now into new product I want to add some extra property
    const newProduct = {
      ...relevantProduct,
      originalPrice: relevantProduct.price
    };

    this.setState({
      cart_products: [...cart_products, newProduct]
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { products, cart_products } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Cart</div>
        {
          cart_products.map((product, index) => <div key={index}>{product.title}</div>)
        }
        <hr />
        <div>Product list</div>
        {
          products.map((product, index) => (
            <div>
              <div key={index}>{product.title}</div>
              <button onClick={() => this.addProductToCart(product.id)}>Add</button>
            </div>)
          )
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: sure no problem, I've added a simple example using your code just in case

Answer (score 2):

I can see some problem at line

```
let productCopy = [...this.state.products];
```

just replace the line with,

```
let productCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([...this.state.products]))
```

*why was it needed?*

that's how the spread operator works while copying the complex variables.
here is the [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) which says,

> **Note**: Spread syntax effectively goes one level deep while copying an
>   array. Therefore, it may be unsuitable for copying multidimensional
>   arrays as the following example shows (it's the same with
>   Object.assign() and spread syntax).

Comment: Your idea is good but it's not valid code I mean according to Standard

Comment: ah, I am bit confused.. why do you think it's not valid? I mean, we need to remove the complex object's reference so that it won't affect the source

Comment: Code is become heavy it's not valid to pass is into JSON and then again convert to object or array.

Comment: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) this works at best when it comes to remove the reference of complex javascript object. other javascript options fail when it comes to handling the multilevel complex object as it does not handle the nested references

Answer (score 0):

> In JS objects are passed by reference.

I'm not sure if you already know this fact but in JS and I guess almost all programming languages, objects are passed by reference. In your code on the following line:

```
// Trying to clone first
 let productCopy = [...this.state.products];
```

...you are creating a new array, `productCopy`, for sure, but even the new array would be having those same exact objects from the previous array `this.state.products` and not some clone of those objects as you are expecting.
You can write your own code for deep cloning of object and arrays. Or, you can make use of some really good JS library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/) as follows:

```js
var arr = [{a:1, b:2}, {c:3, d:4}]

var newArr = _.cloneDeep(arr);
newArr[0].e = 5;
console.log(arr[0]);
console.log(newArr[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes i know but I want solution